# Windows Phone LiveSDK Sign-in System.NotSupportedException in System.Windows.dll

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-live

I have a simple Windows Phone App (7.1) that uses the LiveSDK and simply asks the user to sign in, grant access, and then is supposed to get their name and display it on the screen. Once I sign in, I get the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll

I have the correct Client ID, and have registered this as a Mobile app.
Anyone know what's happening here?
Re: the Redirect URL, i just left it blank since this is just a mobile app- and didn't specify one while setting up the Client ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You know I just ran into this same issue and it was confusing me for a bit. Then two things hit me.

1. It's a first chance exception
2. It's caught and handled by the Live SDK

I was too busy researching the error to try to actually continue through it :) Anyway it works fine if you let it continue.